# Track time spent in MSCRM

Tags: calendar, dynamics-crm, auditing

My requirement is  I need to be able to track time for each sales person on activities.  Also a report that administrators can run to see the amount of time each user spent working on calls/sales/opportunities etc.

What should I use to track how long is user using particular activities?

I think I can do it using auditing.

Do you have any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

User Auditing isnt going to be much help here, for starters it only reports every couple of hours and secondly you cant write report against for the audit table.

I would suggest adding a duration field to entities you want to track time against - activities already have a field for this. Then users just have to manually populate this.

Or if you want to automate you could use form JavaScript, for example:

1. New Field: Number, Duration
2. On Form Load: Capture a start time
3. On Form Save: Capture an end time
4. On Form Save: Work out the difference between the two, then add to the duration field

You would have to do this for every entity you want to track though. Its also not guaranteed to be accurate, for example if a user opens a couple of records at once, or goes to lunch, or just doesnt save the record immediately a much longer Duration could be recorded than actually occurred.